# Having problems building a project with Maven

Tags: java, maven, build

I've just started work on a project that uses maven. However, when I try to build the project I get the following error:

```
MyClass.java:[7,2] annotations are not supported in -source 1.3
(use -source 5 or higher to enable annotations)
@Override
```

I have the latest JRE installed on my machine, and I have tried editing the pom.xml file to fix this but I have had no luck. I've also tried searching Google but I've come up with near nothing.

Does anyone know how I can configure the project to use the latest JRE? Or another solution if this isn't the problem.

Thanks in advance.

(Also, I have never used Maven before so forgive me if anything I say sounds stupid)

**EDIT:** I am using maven from the terminal in the latest Ubuntu release

Comment: are you using maven from the command line, or integrated in IDE? Which version of Maven you're using? What OS?

Comment: I am using maven from the terminal in the latest Ubuntu release. My apologies. I've updated the post

Comment: Please post your pom.xml, that might be really helpful

Comment: Right,than what do you see on  executing: echo $JAVA_HOME with your user? You have sun-jdk installed, right?

Comment: I was missing one part of the pom.xml file. Christian Uhl posted the answer. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you have configured an older version of the JRE within your pom.xml.

Does your pom.xml contain something like this?

```
    <properties>
            <java.version>1.6</java.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
            <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                            <configuration>
                                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                            </configuration>
                    </plugin>
            </plugins>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 2):

Open your pom.xml and search for plug-in with artifact ID maven-compiler-plugin. Check tag . It seems it is 1.3 in your case. Change it to 1.5 (unless you really have to compile your code for JVM 1.3. In this case you should remove the stuff that is not compatible with this old version - e.g. annotations.)